# Cursor with Spring Data Mongo Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to return a cursor with spring data's mongodb aggregation?

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("_id").is(objId)),
            unwind("taskResultContent"),
            project("taskResultContent.executionUUID","taskResultContent.returnContent","taskResultContent.sequency").and("resultID").previousOperation(),
            match(Criteria.where("executionUUID").is(executionUUID)),
            sort(DESC,"sequency")
        ).withOptions(Aggregation.newOptions().cursor(cursor).build());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring data for mongodb does not support the use of a cursor when aggregating. The MongoDB java driver must be used instead.

Comment: Unfortunately not supported. This is the JIRA issue: [DATAMONGO-939](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-939)

Answer (score 5):

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510855/streaming-the-result-of-an-aggregate-operation-using-spring-data-mongodb)
Quoting here :

From spring-data-mongo version 2.0.0.M4 onwards (AFAIK) MongoTemplate got an aggregateStream method.

So you can do the following:

```
 AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = Aggregation.newAggregationOptions()
    // this is very important: if you do not set the batch size, 
    // you'll get all the objects at once and you might run out of memory
    // if the returning data set is too large
    .cursorBatchSize(mongoCursorBatchSize)
    .build();

data = mongoTemplate.aggregateStream(Aggregation.newAggregation(
       Aggregation.group("person_id")
                  .count()
                  .as("count"))
                  .withOptions(aggregationOptions), collectionName, YourClazz.class);
```